# Variable not passed to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass a variable from within my main UIViewController to a UIView.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,347, 308);
XBMCPopUpView * xbmcpop = [[XBMCPopUpView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

xbmcpop.DevIP = @"2222";

[self.view addSubview:xbmcpop];
```

the Object xbmcpop gets created and its string property "DevIP" gets assigned correctly. But when the UIVIEW is actually viewed it seems like the instance that is viewed is different from the one I created and the variable @"2222" is not passed to the string property "DevIP"

Note: My Main UIViewController is in a storyboard with a navigation controller

If you are interested to see the "XBMCPopUpView class, here it is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class XBMCPopUpView;


@interface XBMCPopUpView : UIView
{
    NSString * DevIP;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *DevIP;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

-(IBAction)sendPlay:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a storyboard, you need to use your view controller's `awakeFromNib` method for this.

When you add  the `awakeFromNib` method, don't forget to call `[super awakeFromNib]` there.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
     [super awakeFromNib];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,347, 308);
    XBMCPopUpView * xbmcpop = [[XBMCPopUpView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    xbmcpop.DevIP = @"2222";
    [self.view addSubview:xbmcpop]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. is awake from nib a method in the UIview or in the UIviewcontroller? Could you please provide some sample code? thanks

Comment: Also, how can you pass variables from many methods to the awakefromnib method. I am just passing @"2222" to simplify my question, but this string in fact is extracted from an sqllite database and is triggered from a button click

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that your view xbmcpop is not in the storyboard. I've corrected the answer and added the code. Let me know if this works.

Comment: In debug view the variable within the object is set properly. but for some reason the actual UI view that shows on the UI is not the once we created in the code! its an instance of the class with empty variables

Comment: How do you know that it's a different instance? In your code (and in my example also), `xbmcpop` is a local reference. How do you access it in the debugger outside this method?

Answer (score 0):

Under

```
@interface XBMCPopUpView : UIView
```

remove

```
{
    NSString * DevIP;
}
```